# Dual Server Configuration Advice Needed

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, redis, unicorn

I have 2 servers up and running 1 website. Our site is mainly for Data. and would like to figure out what the best configuration of processes that i should have set for each server to get the best preformance.

Usering the following:

```
Nginx, PosgreSQL, Redis, Unicorn, Ruby 1.9.3, Ruby on Rails 3
```

Server configuration:

Server 1 (MAIN)

```
Godaddy Ultimate VPS 
24 cores
• OS: Linux CentOS 6.4
• RAM: 8 GB
• Storage: 240 GB
• Bandwidth: 8,000 GB/mo

Hosting Main Site & Database & running task

Server 2
Godaddy Premium VPS
24 cores
• OS: Linux CentOS 6.5
• RAM: 4 GB
• Storage: 120 GB
• Bandwidth: 4,000 GB/mo

Hosting Secondary site(same as Main) & Redis server
```

I need help with maximizing the potential of our site. I currently have the servers set to have:

8 instances of redis  resque-1.21.0 (only on redis Server)
16 instances of nginx  Worker Processes
8 instances of Unicorn

Our site gets approximately 1000 - 4000 files a day that it parses thru and post to our database with approximately 200,000 database additions daily.

we currently have approximately 200 visitors daily searching and posting individually as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the [Server 2] box you should have more RAM memory for having short execution time from the code to the Redis db. 'More' means the RAM size should be greater than 30 GB.

DG